# Django with DRF APIs slows down after few weeks or months

Tags: python, django, performance, django-rest-framework, comparison

I have Django with DRF website and it has couple of APIs based on DRF with GenericAPI view and API view. The APIs is used to calculate XML vs XML and JSON vs JSON differences. Two objects are passed as body to these APIs and the API returns the no of differences and exact nodes at which the differences are found. It also respond with nodes which are added or removed.

The sight and APIs work just fine when my environment is just up and running for few weeks say 2 weeks. I have recently observed that after a month or 3 weeks same APIs takes much more time to calculate the differences with same set of data.

Usually it is very fast for example If we have large JSON object then 1k differences per second is processed. If we have pretty small JSON or XML object like 5 to 10 keys (very basic) the main library function which calculates the difference tales just about few milliseconds. So overall API time is like 200 ms.

**Now the issue that I have is after lets say 3 weeks or a month same very basic JSON object comparison (with just 5-10 keys) takes 20 seconds to respond. The library function takes almost 20 seconds to calculate just one or two difference.**

I am not using any caching here. No Database operations are involved in any of my library function.

I do use dict and list data types in python to store the differences calculated. Any idea why does this happen?

Infra details:

1. 4VCPU machine with 16 GB ram (AWS t3.xlarge)
2. docker compose environment with nginx, gunicorn django

Comment: Have you checked whether you RAM usage increases over time?

Comment: yes. My RAM is on heavy usage. even though no website traffic. here are the details.

my RAM is almost full

Comment: I saw one important issue here is that my RAM usage increases after each API call and it never reduces. I have many functions calling another function inside and iterations over which exchanges dictionary and set and list data types. I have optimised the code recently. But the issue with always increasing memory usage have not gone yet

Comment: Do you save your files locally? Do you close them properly to free memory? Do you keep some data somehow stored in memory instead of freeing it?

Comment: I do nothing with files locally. 
What I have done so far is that I pretty much have same issue that if my API view is getting called 100 times it increase my memory by 10 MB each i.e ~1GB and I need to restart my server always to free up memory. I don't even have CACHE but this still occur. I used cProfile and memory profile in python and I see that after every request def post(request) function of my API view allocates ~10 MB to some JSON dict data which I am sending back as a response (Response(data=dict_data)) and it always increases my memory never turns it down.